# How to force flyway only run on one node in a multi-node environment?

Tags: java, oracle, flyway

Hope this is not a repeated question.  I run into an issue that we have an application using flyway, which can be installed and configured as a cluster of node. Flyway support parallel migration of Database (in our case, Oracle), but somehow it is not 'acceptable' for our OPS team's policy due to some 'serious' reason.
  Before answering: "Just do it anyway and let OPS buy it", really unfortunately, we have certain organizational resistance of such change. So my question is:
Is there anyway I can force only one node running Flyway (JAVA API) but leave other nodes not doing any DB Migration?